# How to float Sidebar from Left to Right

Tags: html, css

I need a bit of help in how to float my Sidebar from left to right.
the `float:right;` style doesn't seem to be effective, any advice?

```css
.sidenav {
  float: right;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10000;
  width: 9.375em;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 6px 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 6px 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 6px 10px;
  padding: 1.5em;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#section-1">Cosmo</a>
  <a href="#section-2">Overview</a>
  <a href="#section-3">Challenge</a>
  <a href="#section-4">How Might We</a>
  <a href="#section-5">Solution</a>
  <a href="#section-6">Project Objective</a>
  <a href="#section-7">Research</a>
  <a href="#section-8">Target Users</a>
  <a href="#section-9">Machine Learning</a>
  <a href="#section-10">Project Design</a>
  <a href="#section-11">User Testing</a>
  <a href="#section-12">Prototype</a>
  <a href="#section-13">Reflections</a>
  <a href="#section-14">Future Improvements</a>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: like always, dont use float for styling purpose. `float` is for floating images within a text. Use `flexbox` or `css-grid` instead!

Comment: ah thank you so much, you solved my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: fixed` moves an element out of the flow. As such `float` will not work as it has no place to float at in the first place. The element is no longer part of the normal flow and will be aligned by the fixed position. Add `right: 0;` to move the element to the right

```css
.sidenav {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  width: 9.375em;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 6px 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 6px 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 6px 10px;
  padding: 1.5em;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#section-1">Cosmo</a>
  <a href="#section-2">Overview</a>
  <a href="#section-3">Challenge</a>
  <a href="#section-4">How Might We</a>
  <a href="#section-5">Solution</a>
  <a href="#section-6">Project Objective</a>
  <a href="#section-7">Research</a>
  <a href="#section-8">Target Users</a>
  <a href="#section-9">Machine Learning</a>
  <a href="#section-10">Project Design</a>
  <a href="#section-11">User Testing</a>
  <a href="#section-12">Prototype</a>
  <a href="#section-13">Reflections</a>
  <a href="#section-14">Future Improvements</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use right and left when you use position:fixed , set them to each value you want in px or others.

Comment: you dont need to set the values in pixel. You can use any unit you want (em, rem, %, vh, vw, px ...)

Answer (score 0):

```
.sidenav {
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
    width: 9.375em;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 10%) 0 6px 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 6px 10px;
    box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 10%) 0 6px 10px;
    padding: 1.5em;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```